# Vanilla JavaScript - Selecting 'this' only specific element with event bubbling

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

With Vanilla JavaScript ES5..

How can I select the card that is hovered and get's it's value? And when hover on other elements, get's their value?

Using bubbling method.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/djYLxx?editors=0010

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="organic-body" data-color="#1f2f1e" style="background-color: rgb(31, 51, 34);">
<div class="container">

  <h5>Hover to change color</h5>

  <div class="organic-list">
  <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="red">
    <h2>Color red</h2>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="blue">
    <h2>Color blue</h2>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="green">
    <h2>Color green</h2>
  </a>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // Select each item
  var organicBody = document.querySelector(".organic-body"),
      organicList = document.querySelector(".organic-list"),
      organicCard = document.querySelectorAll(".organic-card");

  // Add event listener to each item
   organicList.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {   

        if(e.target.className === 'organic-card') {
           var text = this.innerText;
           console.log(text);
        }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the `e.target.parentNode` has the specific `class` via:

```
parent.className.indexOf('organic-card') > -1
```

...then get the `innerText` of the `parentNode`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Select each item
  var organicBody = document.querySelector(".organic-body"),
    organicList = document.querySelector(".organic-list"),
    organicCard = document.querySelectorAll(".organic-card");

  // Add event listener to each item
  organicList.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentNode;
    
    if (parent.className.indexOf('organic-card') > -1) {
      var text = parent.innerText;
      console.log(text);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="organic-body" data-color="#1f2f1e" style="background-color: rgb(31, 51, 34);">
  <div class="container">
    <h5>Hover to change color</h5>
    <div class="organic-list">
      <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="red">
        <h2>Color red</h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="blue">
        <h2>Color blue</h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="green">
        <h2>Color green</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select only `organic-card` dom and add event listener to it.

```js
var organicCard = document.querySelectorAll(".organic-card");
organicCard.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML)

  })
})
```

```html
<div class="organic-body" data-color="#1f2f1e" style="background-color: rgb(31, 51, 34);">
  <div class="container">

    <h5>Hover to change color</h5>

    <div class="organic-list">
      <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="red">
        <h2>Color red</h2>
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="blue">
        <h2>Color blue</h2>
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="green">
        <h2>Color green</h2>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to do it with bubbling delegation.